Why is the LEN function outputting the wrong amount of amount characters in my cell?
Why is the LEN function outputting the wrong amount of amount characters in my cell? I am trying to find the number of characters in the date time formatted cell: ex. 12/06/2021 10:23:11. -  I am getting 15 characters which doesn't make sense in this context.
I was expecting 19 characters.

Dates are stored as doubles in Excel and formatted to look like a date.  Excel stores doubles with 15 sig digits, which is why you get 15.

What are you trying to do with LEN?

When cell value is a date it's stored in a different way (as number of days starting from 01.01.1900).
So, 12/06/2021 10:23:11 = 44359.4327662037. That's the value LEN tries to process in your case.
Just convert date to text using TEXT(A1, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss") and then use LEN.
If you use TEXT first, it'll work the way you want.

Excel sees date and time differently to a person.
From Microsoft DATE function help page:

Excel stores dates as sequential serial numbers so that they can be used in calculations. January 1, 1900 is serial number 1, and January 1, 2008 is serial number 39448 because it is 39,447 days after January 1, 1900.

So day 1 is 1/1/1900 00:00:00.
Day 1000 is 29/09/1902 00:00:00.
Day 44000 is 18/06/2020 00:00:00.
Day 44359 is 12/06/2021 00:00:00.
The decimals are parts of a day within the day of 12/06/2021.
Day 44359.5 is 12/06/2021 12:00:00.
If you enter the values above and set the cell to a custom date format of dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss you'll see the output described above.

So 12/06/2021 10:23:11 according to Excel is 44359.4327662037, and the length of that value is 16.
To get the length of the date and time value if treated as a string
Convert the value to a text format, and then get the length of that.
e.g. if cell A1 is 12/06/2021 10:23:11, use the following formula:
=LEN(TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")). This returns 19.
